# Непонятные вещи с кавычками в регулярке php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте.

Можете сказать, правильно ли я написал регулярку по поиску содержимого в кавычках?

```
preg_match_all('/("|\')(.*)("|\')/iU', '0:1:2;;3:4:5:6:7;;8:"9,10,,","12,13",23:24;25:26;27:\'28\';;;14:15,16,17,18,19,20,21:22;;;', $matches);
```

Меня смущает один момент. А именно, вывод получается такой:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => "9,10,,"
            [1] => "12,13"
            [2] => '28'
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => "
            [1] => "
            [2] => '
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9,10,,
            [1] => 12,13
            [2] => 28
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => "
            [1] => "
            [2] => '
        )
)
```

Я просто привык к тому, что выводится 2 значения, а тут мне целых 4. Это так и должно быть, или я чего-то напутал, как всегда?

Comment: Сколько круглых скобок - столько и значений +1 полное совпадение. А регулярка думаю не правильная. `.*` захватит все до последней кавычки, если нужны ближайшие то лучше `.*?` и выбор вариантов из одного символа проще делать в квадратных скобках. итого `[\'"](.*?)[\'"]` и групп захвата лишних не будет

Comment: @Mike, спасибо, не знал, что это влияет на количество результатов. Выводит на 5 баллов.

Comment: @Mike там модификатор **U**, так что всё нормально.

Comment: @ReinRaus, убрал модификаторы, получилось вот так: `'/[\'"](.*?)[\'"]/'`

Comment: `/(["']).*?\1/` вот так совсем хорошо будет.

Comment: @ReinRaus выдаёт: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ']'`

Comment: Вариант Mike, подходит отлично

Comment: Потому что экранировать надо, а не просто копировать.  Я привел регулярное выражение, каким образом Вы его поместите его в Вашу программу- исключительно Ваше решение.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно выводит - массив с индексом 0 - это все совпадения с шаблоном pattern, остальные - это часть шаблона pattern, которая подходит под шаблон в скобках. так как у вас три части значений в скобках, соответственно и 3 дополнительных индекса. В [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match-all.php) вы можете посмотреть как можно управлять выводом с помощью флага

Comment: Спасибо, у меня с регулярками туго получается. Со ссылкой, которую вы прислали я был знаком. Несколько раз читал.